# Caps+shift+{w/s/x} doesn't work in gnome

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

I have rebind my CapsLock key to ctrl in my Gnome DE(GNOME Shell 3.14.3
) using the Gnome Tweak Tool(i.e `Tweak Tool -> Typing -> CapsLock key behaviour -> Make CapsLock an additional Ctrl`).
Even though everything works fine except when I use these combinations:

1. Caps+Shift+w
2. Caps+Shift+s
3. Caps+Shift+x

However any other key combinations using Caps+Shift+{...} work.
Also as a precautionary hardware check I ran `xev` and it does list 'w', 'W'... but not the above mentioned combinations
P.S: I use ArchLinux if it matters,

$ cat /proc/version
    Linux version 3.18.6-1-ARCH (builduser@tobias) (gcc version 4.9.2 20141224 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Feb 7 08:44:05 CET 2015